# What are single layer and double layer potentials?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

I have never encountered the terms "single layer potential" and "double layer potential" in my (under)graduate studies, although there was a firm development of partial differential equations and some harmonic analysis.

Where can I learn the basic principles about that? Are these techniques related/equivalent to other known techniques?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_layer_potential

Comment: This article does not provide very much information, and it does not explain single layer potentials. Where does that name come from?

Comment: I gave the link not for the article itself but for the references on it. :)

Answer (score 2):

This two-page article may help:

https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/potphys.pdf